# .txt read to change global varibles

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm having a player input his/her name. The name is written to a file. Then the file is opened, read and the global variable is changed to what was in said file. This is eventually going to get worked into a save feature for a game I am developing for a class.

```
def nameWrite():
    text_file = open("name.txt", "w+")
    print('what u name')
    text_file.write(input())
    text_file.close()

def nameRead():
    text_file = open("name.txt","r")
    print ("This is the output in file:",text_file.read())
    global playerName
    playerName = text_file.read()
    text_file.close()

nameWrite()
nameRead()
print("You name is now:",playerName)
```

Why does this not change the variable `playerName`?

Comment: the global variable isnt updating

Comment: The code looks like it could work, what's the problem?  I don't really like the use of `global`; it would be preferable to just have your `nameRead()` function `return playerName`.

Comment: When you call `.read()` the file contents are read. The second time you call `.read()` there is nothing more to read and the empty string is returned. A possible solution is to assign the file contents to the variable before printing the contents.

Comment: @bernie thank you god I feel dumb

Comment: @JohnBrook: Please do not feel that way. That feeling can only sabotage your productivity. We all have been there at one point. Go find the next bug!

Comment: @JohnBrook: My +1 to Nick T -- avoid using global variables. They are not not neccessary at all. They only complicate things when the problem becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable *is*  updating, just not updating to what you think it should.

Take a look at this code:

```
def nameRead():
    text_file = open("name.txt","r")                         # 1
    print ("This is the output in file:",text_file.read())   # 2
    global playerName
    playerName = text_file.read()                            # 3
    text_file.close()
```

When it executes, this is what happens:

1. the file is opened
2. ALL of the data in the file is read, and the file pointer is moved to the end of the file
3. The next time you read, there is no more data to be read so playerName is the empty string

You can't read from a file twice unless you either close and reopen it, or use the `seek` function to move the file pointer back to the beginning.